# PTV Vissim - is there a way to change the colour of static 3d objects?

Tags: ptv-vissim

Looking through the list of static 3d objects (v3d files) they are all white.  When you play the simulation, moving 3d objects are automatically coloured.  Is there a simple way to change the colour of the static 3d objects in Vissim?

Comment: Most of the Vissim community exchanges happen on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2524087). So you might get faster answers there. Or you could also contact PTV's technical support.

Comment: Thanks @Sedonion, yup I discovered linkedin's forum (stackexchange is a better suited but I guess not if the users aren't there!)